# Generate sine wave samples that can be repeated without phase jumps

Tags: rust, signal-processing

I need to generate samples of a sine wave to play them as audio. The frequency range is 200 to 2000Hz with 1Hz steps. This is part of an embedded project and I wan to spent as little time as possible on generating the audio samples. My solution to this is to generate a single period worth of samples and repeatedly play them until the tone frequency needs to be changed, at which point I would generate new samples.

```rust
use std::f32::consts::TAU;

const SAMPLE_RATE: u32 = 8000;
const BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 100;

fn main() {
    let mut values = Vec::new();

    let mut buffer = [0f32; BUFFER_SIZE];

    let mut tone_generator = ToneGenerator { phase: 0.0 };

    let count = tone_generator.generate_samples(&mut buffer, 495, 0.0);
    values.extend_from_slice(&buffer[0..count]); // Pretend this is pushing the samples to a FIFO
    values.extend_from_slice(&buffer[0..count]); // Repeat the same values
    values.extend_from_slice(&buffer[0..count]); // Again
    let count = tone_generator.generate_samples(&mut buffer, 496, 0.0); // New samples
    values.extend_from_slice(&buffer[0..count]); // Etc.
    values.extend_from_slice(&buffer[0..count]);
    let count = tone_generator.generate_samples(&mut buffer, 497, 0.0);
    values.extend_from_slice(&buffer[0..count]);
    values.extend_from_slice(&buffer[0..count]);

    // Plot all the samples
    let mut plot = plotly::Plot::new();
    let ts = values
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(ts, _)| ts as f32 / SAMPLE_RATE as f32)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let trace = plotly::Scatter::new(ts, values.clone())
        .name("sin")
        .mode(plotly::common::Mode::LinesMarkers);
    plot.add_trace(trace);
    plot.show();
}

struct ToneGenerator {
    phase: f32,
}

impl ToneGenerator {
    fn generate_samples<'a>(
        &'a mut self,
        buffer: &'a mut [f32; BUFFER_SIZE],
        frequency: u32,
        volume_db: f32,
    ) -> usize {
        let delta = frequency as f32 * TAU / SAMPLE_RATE as f32;
        let amplitude = libm::powf(10.0, volume_db / 20.).min(1.0);

        let mut count = 0;

        for value in buffer.iter_mut() {
            *value = self.phase.sin() * amplitude;
            count += 1;

            self.phase += delta;
            if self.phase > TAU {
                self.phase -= TAU;
                break;
            }
        }

        count
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I increase the tone frequency in 1Hz steps, the change in sound between steps is not constant. I think there are two reason for this:

1. The number of audio samples for a single period depends on the tone frequency. When the change in frequency cause a change in the number of the number of samples the perceived change in tone (and also volume) is much larger than when the number of samples stays the same.
2. For some frequencies there is a notable phase jump when a sample is repeated, as visible in the plot from the code above:
   [image: sine]

Is there a way to solve these problems without needing to generate new samples when the frequency does not change? To me these two requirements seem conflicting to me but maybe there is a technique to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your point 1: the number of samples is directly related to the period length, which is the inverse frequency so of course the number of samples in a period depends on the frequency. And obviously changing the frequency changes the perceived tone (but not the volume).

Comment: As for your point 2, this shift occurs each time the sample rate cannot be divided by the frequency of the tone, so you need to either adjust slightly the frequency so that it will result in a round number of samples per period, or generate all the samples dynamically. Note that this "phase shift" as you call it does result in a tone whose actual fundamental frequency _is_ slightly different from the one you requested.

Comment: I think that explains why frequencies with the same number of samples sound so similar. Due to the phase shift they are more of less the same.

Comment: I was hoping for some clever way to make the repeating samples "connect" better without dynamically generating the samples. I don't see how that's possible but I wanted to ask anyway

Answer (score 2):

If you repeat a waveform with a certain period (determined here by the sample count), then it will contain only frequencies which are a multiple of that fundamental frequency, the reciprocal of the period. It's impossible to do anything else; the mathematics of signals tells us this. (Consider what the Fourier transform of your signal is.)

Therefore, in order to have more precise frequency selection with pre-generated waves, you must make them longer — in particular, in order to fill the gap between the period "N samples" and "N+1 samples", you need to generate a signal with (N × 2) + 1 samples which contains two periods of the wave. This is not redundant data, because the middle section has different samples than the ends.

Or instead, to use a lot less storage, you can change the frequency of a single waveform during playback by resampling (interpolating between stored samples) — but I believe that works out to being equivalent to generating a sine wave using a sine lookup table.

Another general strategy is to generate the wave by rotating a unit vector (or equivalently a complex number).

1. From the frequency, calculate a rotation matrix for the change in phase for a single sample.
2. Store the vector (x and y, or i and j, or sin and cos), initially equal to (0, 1)
3. To generate the next sample, multiply the vector by the rotation matrix, then take one of the two numbers in the vector (either one) as the output sample.
4. Occasionally correct for numerical error by normalizing the vector (divide it by its length).

This requires calculating a square root for the normalization, but no sines or cosines except when initialzing.